# Heapsize error with executeBatch JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, heap-memory

I'm using addBatch / executeBatch to insert some records in Oracle database table, but I've encountered the following heapsize error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(Array.java:52)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.BufferCache.get(BufferCache.java:212)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getCharBuffer(PhysicalConnection.java:7422)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setupBindBuffers(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2826)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9973)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:213)
```

I've added the following parameter

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
```

while calling the program with no luck.
Adding the 1024m was fine for 180k records but it keeps crashing at 290k. I tried to increase it to 4024m but it does not help.

Comment: have you tried `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();` to find total memory for JVM

Comment: Don't execute the whole batch at once as all that data needs to be kept in memory until all statements have been executed; collect a sufficiently large number (eg somewhere between 100 and 1000) and execute.

Answer (score 0):

For every setting of the memory parameter you will find a record number that will fail.

Divide the rows in blocks of a manageable size and issue after adding of each block

```
 sendBatch()
```

In Oracle you may also set

```
setExecuteBatch(blockSize)
```

where `blockSize`is the number of rows that will be passed in each roundtrip.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I appreciate if you elaborate as I'm newbie to JAVA and jdbc

Comment: pls check some tutorial on this topic, e.g. for [Oracle Update Batching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/oraperf.htm)